# Is there a way for VSCode file associations to work for partial naming?

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

I would like my material-icon-theme to recognize files as docker-compose-*.yml as docker files, however the command below does not work in my settings.json

```
"material-icon-theme.files.associations": {
    "docker-compose*.yml": "docker"
  }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For sure man, you just simply use regex to catch the file name, such as

```json
 "material-icon-theme.files.associations": {
    "docker-compose.*.yml": "dockerfile"
  }
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: This doesn't work for me.